# Phrase - 'stop with...'

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

Is 'stop with (noun)' a correct construction to use?
For example, can I say:

> 'Please stop with your criticism towards...'

To mean the same thing as 'stop criticizing...'

Another example would be:

> I would like you to stop with your antics.

If possible, please justify your answer by providing a link to a reference, provided that the use of 'stop with' is grammatical.

Also, how reliable is google advanced book search in terms of using it to check your English? Do incorrect expressions pop up from time to time. If a search yielded more than one page of results, should I be confident that the search is of good English?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The topic seems to have been addressed before. Have you seen this?: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362737/stop-with-the

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. I must say neglected looking for it on the usage forum. However, instead of taking down the question,I would still like to see if it can be addressed in further details here, preferably with the provision of a reference website. I would also like to read some opinions people might have on advanced book search.